# Set Validation.ErrorTemplate in code behind

Tags: wpf, validation, code-behind

How can I set the Validation.ErrorTemplate property in code behind?

Answer (score 2):

Thats very straight forward.

You can use the below code,

```
Validation.SetErrorTemplate(this.editor, Resources["MyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate);
```

Regards,

Jawahar